# How to remove select tag outline

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I remove [The outline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjoAP.png) from this select & options tags ?

I used

```
       .languages { //select tag
            border: none;
            background-color: $bg1;
            -webkit-appearance: none;

            &:focus {
                outline: none;
                border: none;
            }

            option { // doesn't work :(
                border: none;
                outline: none; 
            }
        }
```

I'm using plain html css and Js for a landing page

Comment: When asking a question, people will be better able to provide help if you provide code that they can easily understand and use to [reproduce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) the problem

Comment: Maybe this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-an-html-select-element) can help you solve your problem

Comment: thanks @Hussein it helped me understand that select is not very "CSS-able" and that i should look for a different solution